# SQL Coding Naming convention: Variable same name as Columns

Tags: sql, coding-standards, sql-server, naming-standards

Is there a coding naming convention principal for SQL variables? Can variables be named the same as column names, I heard in different companies, this may cause confusion. However in C# below, its a generally accepted principle, resource below.

```
create table dbo.Product
( 
    ProductId int primary key null,
    ProductName varchar(25) not null,
    ProductDescription varchar(255) not null
)


create procedure dbo.ProductNameUpdate 
@ProductId int, @ProductName varchar(255)
as

update dbo.Product
set 
ProductName = @ProductName
where ProductId = @ProductId
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229060(v=vs.100).aspx
https://www.dotnetperls.com/constructor

```
public Product(int ProductId, int ProductName)
        {
            this.ProductId= ProductId;
            this.ProductName= ProductName;
        }
```

Comment: Well, clearly variable names can be named the same as column names, as your example attests.  There's no confusion (other than your odd choice of brace spacing), because the variables are always disambiguated, either by an @ sign or the `this` keyword.

Comment: I’ve never heard the term “brace spacing” @RobertHarvey and google failed me. What’s it referring to?

Comment: @Paul Indentation.

Comment: Oh, I assumed that was just a transcription error due to Stack’s code formatter.

Comment: Having database field names the same as their variable counterparts the same makes sense in an environment where the language or tools enforce additional chars on variable names. 
There is this same problem when you pass variables into a function with the same name as the variables local to the function. The long term question is maintenance time. How much time is lost as developers try to figure out or remember what's what.

Answer (score 1):

Different languages have different naming conventions. For example, in Python fields [*should*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?#method-names-and-instance-variables) be formatted using snake case like `product_id` and `product_name`. If you ignore such conventions your code is going to be **less idiomatic,** and unless you use camel case for fields everywhere it is going to be **inconsistent.** Both of these will hurt readability. Of course, if you happen to only ever use a single language and a single database which happen to have the same naming conventions, go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is it acceptable to have column names the same as variables, most ORM tools will do so by default, following the naming conventions of whatever language is building the application.